Are there any downsides in converting a Slack direct message into a private Slack channel?
I'm considering converting a Slack message into a private Slack Channel.
Are there any downsides in converting a Slack direct message into a private Slack channel? (E.g., missing features)

After searching for a while and consulting several people, there appears to be no downsides, aside from the fact that clicking on "message" under someone's profile won't point to that 1:1 channel.
